# Attempting to concatenate strings produces a segmentation fault

Tags: c, gcc

I'm attempting to convert command-line arguments into a single `char*` or "c-string" reference, however it seems my code is breaking. There aren't any compiler warnings, so I'm a bit stuck at this point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: program <arguments>");
        return 0;
    }
    char* string = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        strcat(string, argv[i]);
    }
    printf("%s", string);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with:

```
gcc program.c -Wall -std=c99 -o prog
```

Doesn't seem to throw any warnings, so where could I be going wrong?

**Edit:**

Updates code to this point:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc == 0) {
        printf("usage: program <arguments>");
        return 1;
    }
    int tot = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        tot += strlen(argv[i]);
    }
    char string[tot + argc]; // total word length
    strcat(string, "\0");
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        strcat(string, argv[i]);
        strcat(string, " ");
    }
    strcat(string, "\0");
    printf("%s", string);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

However a new problem arises, in that it appears to prepend pseudo-random garbage characters to the string. I added this to the catenation loop to look at the output:

```
for (int w = 0; w < sizeof(argv[i]); w++) {
    printf("\t%s%c\n", "char value: ", argv[i][w]);
}
```

And this was the output:

```
./prog one two three
    char value: o
    char value: n
    char value: e
    char value:
    char value: t
    char value: w
    char value: o
    char value:
    char value: t
    char value: h
    char value: r
    char value: e
Tëñ¿one two three
```

So my guess is that the issue lays within the argument not having a proceeding `\0` value, but not 100% certain of how to proceed. Would creating a new array of `char` to append to, then catenating that be appropriate?

Comment: You must allocate enough of space to `string`. C strings are not resized automatically.

Comment: @Marian so I would check the length of the thing that I am appending, but how would I change the space for the variable `string` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count the total space first:

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    total += strlen(argv[i]);
}
```

Then allocate space for final string:

```
string = calloc(1, total+1);
```

+1 is for null terminator ('\0').
Then you can strcat to string, and remeber to free it when you don't need it anymore.

Here is the full working code (without error checking):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int total = 0;
    int i;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: program <arguments>");
        return 0;
    }
    char *string;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            total += strlen(argv[i]);
    }
    string = calloc(1, total+1);
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            strcat(string, argv[i]);
    }   
    printf("%s", string);
    printf("\n");

    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've read somewhere that `malloc` can have incorrect outputs, is there an alternative to that function?

Comment: Of course you need to do some error checking for malloc(calloc) return, and strcat() require a clear space(at least a leading '\0').

Comment: Hm, looking at your full code, wouldn't it be simpler (since you're checking all sizes first) to just make a new `char string[total + argc + 1]` (argc for delimiting)?

Comment: It's okay, depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I've made quite a bit of progress but landed at a final issue (random characters). I updated the question if you have any insight :)

Comment: You need to study how C string work first, `strcat(string, "\0");` make zero sense. And try to clean space by memset() before using it(so like malloc()).

Answer (score 0):

the way you declare `string` make the memory that `string` point to can't be modified.

Instead, you can declare `string` as char array if you know max size needed. And you'd beter do length checking to make sure it's not overrun when you do `strcat`

```
char string[1024]; // put the size you needed
```

Or you can dynamically allocate space. As suggested by @moeCake.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to write into a literal string. Two problems:
1) literal strings aren't generally placed in writable memory.
2) the string (character array) is of size zero; there's no room to write in to it.

The quick answer is to allocate a buffer on the heap:

```
char* string = (char*)malloc(256);
```

or on the stack:

```
char string[256];
```

Ideally you'd avoid picking a constant size like 256. One approach would be to loop over argv twice - once to measure how much space you'll need, and then again to perform the copies.